# How can i convert XUL to XHTML?

Tags: html, xul

Anyone know of any tools or techniques for converting xul to x/html?  I've got a xul window I created for a Firefox addon that I now want to port over to html.

Any tips, links, or tricks would be helpful.

Thanks,
-=Vin

Answer (score 1):

A suitable technique for such a conversion is using [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt).